# Date is different that in database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, quarkus

In my Quarkus app I have object which is the same as a table in database that have a java.sql.Timestamp createDate field. In database example date is shown as a: 2022-02-17 18:16:00 in PST time but when I get the object through JPA from MySQL database as a Timestamp is:  2022-02-18 02:16:00.0 which looks like UTC time.

In application properties I have:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.jdbc.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

which means that database is configured in PST time.

Any ides why time zone is different in java object from database data?

Comment: Sure, so why this timestamp in database is different than getting it through JPA in java?

Comment: But why it's changing time zone? I want get values from database as it is.

Comment: What happens if you use a java.time.ZonedDateTime to receive the information from the database? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html .

Comment: I'm used java.sql.Timestamp to receive information from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue.
In the datebase table time field, the time is different 8 oclock from the app server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).